# Navbar won't go back to normal after screen size shrinks

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, navbar

I am creating a football website and am working on the navbar. I created code so that when it shrinks, it becomes collapsible with a hamburger button. However, if I make the screen wide again the navbar content doesn't show anymore.

Here is my code below:

```js
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar')
let number = 0

function toggleFunction() {

  console.log(getComputedStyle(navbar).display)
  if (number === 1) {
    navbar.style.display = 'none'
    number -= 1
  } else {
    navbar.style.display = 'inline-block'
    navbar.style.position = 'absolute'
    navbar.style.top = '75px'
    navbar.style.width = '100%'
    navbar.style.textAlign = 'center'
    navbar.style.padding = ' 5px 0'
    navbar.style.background = 'orange'
    navbar.style.height = "auto";
    number += 1
  }

  console.log(navbar)
}
```

```css
.toggle-btn {
  width: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.toggle-btn span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
  }
  #navbar {
    display: none;
  }
  #header {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
  #navbar {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-left: 15%;
    align-self: center;
    height: 75px;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

#header {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 75px;
}

#navbar {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-left: 15%;
  align-self: center;
  height: 75px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleFunction()">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<nav id="header">
  <img src="pantherlogo.png" alt="Beverly Panthers Logo" id="logo">
  <div id="navbar">
    <h3><a href="index.html">HOME</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="team.html">TEAMS</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="history.html">HISTORY</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="contacts.html">CONTACTS</a></h3>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="top">
  <img src="footballimg.png" alt="football" id="footballimg">
  <div id="motto">
    <h1>Restore our pride.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1:

Resizing the screen, will hide the nav items and show the burger button that will expand which will reveal the items. Resizing the screen *without* first clicking on the burger button will cause the screen to look like it did in the beginning.

Scenario 2:

Resizing the screen, will hide the nav items and show the burger button that will expand which will reveal the items.
If you **click** on the burger button, then the event listener will run the `toggleFunction` (event handler callback) and the `navbar` element (`div#navbar`) will be hidden, as inside the `toggleFunction` you explicitly set `style.display = "none"`.
If you resize the screen again, your media queries and CSS classes will have no effect since setting the `style` attribute inline (with or without js) causes the rule to prevail over other selectors (CSS specificity).

**Suggested solution (general)**:

Create some utility classes for the "hidden" and "visible" states of your navbar, then apply *those classes* in your even handler.

E.g.

```css
/* In your CSS file */
.visible {
  display: inline-flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #navbar {
    display: none;
    /* other modifications to styling */
  }
}
```

then in your JS:

```js
function toggleFunction() {
  navbar.classList.toggle("visible"); // element.classList.toggle("class-name") will add the class "class-name" to the element if it wasn't there before, or it will remove it if it was already applied to the element
}
```

**Suggested solution (specific)**

In your case, you should remove the stylings for `navbar` at the bottom of your file to avoid CSS specificity issues.

```css
/* Remove this */
#navbar {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-left: 15%;
    align-self: center;
    height: 75px;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And add the following rule inside your media query for your mobile view

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    /* Your other rules here */

    #navbar.visible {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 75px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0px;
        background: orange;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

This rule will apply the desired styling to you `navbar` when it has the class `visible` applied to it.

Then, replace your `toggleFunction` with the version I suggest above, so that it will add/remove the `visible` class whenever the user clicks on the burger button.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I tried to put it into the function, but it didn't change anything. I also tried putting it in an if/else function before the toggleFunction(), but that didn't work either.

Comment: I provided a specific suggested solution that will solve your problem. However, if you don't understand what the solution does, I suggest you take a look at DOM manipulation. Consider upvoting if you found this useful!